# Text in outer margin of multiple columns

Tags: context, marginpar, context-mkiv

I want to put some text in the outer margin (by which I mean on the left side of the page of even pages and on the right side of odd pages) of the page. My naive approach of using `\inoutermargin{Text}` fails when I use it with columns. Then the text is printed in the outer margin of the first column. Can somebody point me into the right direction?

I am using ConTeXt  ver: 2012.05.30 11:26 MKIV

```
\starttext

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\startcolumns
\inoutermargin{More text}
\input knuth
\stopcolumns

\page[yes]

\startcolumns
\inoutermargin{Text}
\input knuth
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

Comment: I deleted my answer. I always count the margin to be the second column. So in a sense you want two text plus one margin column?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the mailing list, it seems that `\inoutermargin` is [deprecated in ConTeXt MkIV](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/060348.html) (that said, I see exactly the same issue in MkII). Taking that plus the [ConTeXt wiki page on `\inoutermargin`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/inothermargin), it seems that you want `\inmargin` to place material on the left or `\inother` to place it on the right:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

\startcolumns
\inmargin{Text}
\input knuth
\inother{More text}
\stopcolumns

\hairline

\inother{Text}
\input knuth

\stoptext
```

---

Further testing suggests to me that the requested behaviour is not so easy to achieve. If you look at `typo-mar.mkiv`, you will find the definitions

```
% text

\definemargindata [inleft]     [\v!left ]    [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\leftmarginwidth ,\c!align=\v!flushright]
\definemargindata [inright]    [\v!right]    [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\rightmarginwidth,\c!align=\v!flushleft]
\definemargindata [inouter]    [\v!outer]    [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\outermarginwidth,\c!align=\v!inner]
\definemargindata [ininner]    [\v!inner]    [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\innermarginwidth,\c!align=\v!outer]

% no longer auto auto-other

\definemargindata [inmargin]   [\v!left]     [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\leftmarginwidth, \c!align=\v!flushright]
\definemargindata [inother]    [\v!right]    [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\rightmarginwidth,\c!align=\v!flushleft]

\definemargindata [margintext] [\v!left]     [\c!margin=\v!margin,\c!width=\leftmarginwidth, \c!align=\v!flushright,\c!stack=\v!yes]
```

Thus you might be led to try

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\starttext

\startcolumns
\inouter{Text}
\input knuth
\inouter{More text}
\stopcolumns

\hairline

\inouter{Text}
\input knuth

\stoptext
```

which does indeed place material in the outer margin (there is `\ininner` for the inner margin). However, this does not seem to account for the presence of multiple columns, *i.e* it is in the 'margin' of the column not the page.

In [`typo-mar.lua`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/typo-mar.lua), line 434 (in the `realign`) function suggests the margintext's box is moved by hsize:

```
            if location == v_left then
                move_x = (reference.x or 0) - (blob.x or 0)
            elseif location == v_right then
                move_x = (reference.x or 0) - (blob.x or 0) + (reference.w or 0) - hsize
            else
```

The `hsize` is as wide as the column one is currently in, and the variable `columns` is defined once and used never in the file. So that, too, suggests columns are not taken into account.